# "Microsoft Visual C++ runtime library" When I use sqlite.dll at Qt executable folder

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, dll

After I built Executable folder, it works fine at development machine. 
But when I copy to target machine. It didn't work.

I continue create a simple project with have just a button and I put a images for it. 
I create `\appfolder\release\imageformats\.dll`. It work fine with this basic project at target machine.

When I add dquest and sqlite database for it. 
I create `\appfolder\release\sqldrivers\qsqlite.dll`. It didn't work at target machine.

Do you have any solution?

Comment: This is very similar to how I deploy my Qt applications. I mean my app gets installed (by default) in c:\Program Files\AppName\bin and the sql drivers folder is in c:\Program Files\AppName\bin\sqldrivers. This has never failed me once.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to install `vcredist` executable on your target machine. This can be found within your MSVC Installation at your development machine. This is needed since you link against the VC-libs when using MSVC as compiler

Comment: yes,I did it. It work fine with simple project. When I run a project which use sqlite connect. It show this error again.

Comment: Please post the exact error. If it is not text link to an image of the error.

Comment: On your second project, be sure to compile in release mode. Also check if your qsql*drivers are in: ``path/to/your/app.exe/sqldrivers/*``